# getElementById problem

Tags: javascript

I call the following function with a mouseover event but it's not working. My id's are all correct & I have properly linked all my external scripts.

```
function new2() {
var prevWin = document.GetElementById("recentlyaddedtip");
prevWin.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

recentlyaddedtip is set as hidden in the stylesheet (and it properly changes to visible when I change it manually.)

Comment: (this is basic stuff, but...) Is the ID value set on the element that you're trying to change? Is the case you're referencing the same as it is set in ID (i.e. all lowercase)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Try:

```
document.getElementById('recentlyaddedtip');
```

Notice the small 'g'.

Comment: The code as normal text was driving me crazy. Fixed. +1 for the being the fastest gun. :)

Comment: Not a problem. And there are folks who provide answers while I am still typing! :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't uppercase the G in GetElementById, it should be getElementById().
JavaScript is case sensitive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var prevWin = document.getElementById("recentlyaddedtip");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is a case sensitive function name.

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementById` should be `getElementById` (note the case)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see your mouseover function so I don't know if that's spelled right, but try:

```
var prevWin = document.getElementById("recentlyaddedtip");
```

with a lowercase g.